# How do I smooth janky movement over ground as rope length is reduced?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, first-person-shooter

Here is a video showing the type of movement I am talking about:
[video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvxeT.jpg)

I have a configurable joint attached to the player which reduces in length every frame the player touches the ground. I do this so that the player has an easier time getting off the ground and it adds a bit extra velocity. The problem is that when the rope shortens it causes the player to bounce across the ground (because the player is pulled toward the anchor then gravity pulls the player back down) which can make the movement seem a bit unpolished. I see two possible ways to solve this, both of which I am unsure on how to do:

1. stop the bouncy movement
2. smooth the camera so the bounce isn't noticed by the player

Here is the code that shortens the rope:

```
if (_playerGameobject.isGrounded())
        {

            SoftJointLimit softJointLimit = new SoftJointLimit();
            ropeLength -= .1f;
            softJointLimit.limit = ropeLength;
            _playerGameobject.playerJoint.linearLimit = softJointLimit;
        }
```

Can someone give me some tips or ideas for this problem?

Comment: This looks like judder due to a lack of rigidbody interpolation. Have you enabled interpolation on your rigidbody? Don't forget to show us your code - there are mutliple ways this could be done, so it's possible a small tweak to your implementation could help.

Comment: @DMGregory I have tried to enable interpolation but it has not improved anything.